# What is the most efficient way or best practice for null check when you use Split and FirstOrDefault methods together?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, split, null-check

I use Split and LastOrDefault methods together, I use this code block for null check. But it does not seems the most efficient way to me. Because I use lots of check and && operators. It seem a little ugly. Is there any way to accomplish this null-check in a better way? (I searched on web but couldn' t find related answers.)

Note : C# Language version 4.0

Here is my code :

```
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Split('/') != null &&
        HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Split('/').Length > 0 &&
        HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Split('/').Last() != null &&
        HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Split('/').Last().Split('.') != null &&
        HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Split('/').Last().Split('.').Length > 0 &&
        HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Split('/').Last().Split('.').First() != null)
    {
        pageName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Split('/').LastOrDefault().Split('.').FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: If you replace `.Last()` with `.LastOrDefault()` you don't need the preceeding length check, same with `First()`.

Comment: If you're using C# 4 you don't have any better option than to have lots of `&&`. You might want to declare some variables along the way to avoid having to re-evaluate Split so many times, but it won't get much better. Why the old C# version?

Comment: Thank you for your comment Lasse, my company has so many products with older .net/c# versions including .net framework 2.0. They have many prequisites about changing framework or language versions. So can't upgrade versions. Instead of upgrade whole products will be developed entirely.

Comment: OK, but you (and your team, company) knows that updating C# does not necessarily require a newer .NET framework, right? You need a newer compiler but it should be able to target older .NET frameworks and still use newer C# versions. There are of course things in newer C# versions that require framework support, but if you either polyfill those in using nuget packages or just custom classes, or just stay away from using them, you should be able to move all the way up to at least C# 7 (I believe). If you have policies, however, ....

Comment: Actually I think so. When I search Advanced build settings menu or LangVersion parameter in csproj  is used for change language version. But I can't find any visual studio 2019-2017-2015 Advanced build settings menu or any csproj with LangVersion config parameter. So I couldn't change it. My WebForm project does not contain any .csproj or equivalent file. (I am not good at WebForm, may be web forms don't not have csproj files.) Visual Studio 2019 webform project -> right click -> property pages -> Build tab-> There is no Avanced build settings option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tests are all not needed:

First, don't run `Split` multiple times on the same data:

```
var splitSlashAbsPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Split('/');
```

The return array from `Split` can never be null

```
//    if (splitSlashAbsPath != null &&
```

the return array from `Split` can never be zero length

```
//        splitSlashAbsPath.Length > 0 &&
```

so the return from `Last()` can never be null

```
//        splitSlashAbsPath.Last() != null &&
```

Don't run split multiple times on the same data (and calling `Last` on an array doesn't make sense)

```
var splitDotAbsPath = splitSlashAbsPath[splitSlashAbsPath.Length-1].Split('.');
```

the return array from `Split` can never be null

```
//        splitDotAbsPath != null &&
```

the return array from `Split` can never be zero length

```
//        splitDotAbsPath.Length > 0 &&
```

so, the `First()` from `Split` can never be null

```
//        splitDotAbsPath.First() != null)
//    {
```

since you can call `Last`, calling `LastOrDefault` makes no sense
same for `FirstOrDefault`

```
//        pageName = splitDotAbsPath.FirstOrDefault();
```

Calling `First` on an array also doesn't make sense

```
pageName = splitDotAbsPath[0];

//    }
```

So, in summary you have:

```
var splitSlashAbsPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Split('/');
var splitDotAbsPath = splitSlashAbsPath[splitSlashAbsPath.Length-1].Split('.');
pageName = splitDotAbsPath[0];
```

However, in general, using `Split` for just getting one element is very inefficient, so this would be better:

```
var path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
var pastSlashPos = path.LastIndexOf('/') + 1;
var countUntilDot = path.IndexOf('.', pastSlashPos);
countUntilDot = (countUntilDot >= 0 ? countUntilDot : path.Length) - pastSlashPos;
pageName = path.Substring(pastSlashPos, countUntilDot);
```

Comment: Hi NetMage, thank you for your answer. It helped a lot actually.

Comment: @cansu I should have put in a non-Split version, which I have added now.